# Warning: Parameter 2 to advanced_custom_search() expected to be a reference

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Basically, I moved a live WordPress website locally to test a few designs but it has given the following error

Warning: Parameter 2 to advanced_custom_search() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 287

For your information, I don’t have advanced custom search installed in my installed plugin list but I have ACF(advanced custom field) plugin

can anyone please help me on this one?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlEdu.png)

Comment: Have you replaced all your DB occourrences from http://myrealdomain.com to http://mylocaldomain.com?

Comment: @Diego I exported the relevent database from the live phpmyadmin and imported in the local phpmyadmin. Am i missing something?

Comment: Since your error comes from wp-hook then it means it could be from ANY plugin / theme code that is using add_action/add_filter/apply_filter/do_action. So, to make sure this is all set you should search inside ALL your database if you have any occourrences of the live site domain. If you find some, you need to replace them. Be careful with serialized data (usually inside wp_postmeta or wp_options

Comment: @Diego I replaced all the live site domain with the local domain but still, the error persists. you said in your comment about ANY plugin/theme code that is using add_action/add_filter/apply_filter/do_action, can you please tell me where exactly it would be and what needs to be changed.

Comment: I would start by searching for "advanced_custom_search" in all your project files. Somewhere, something must use that function

Comment: I found that function (advanced_custom_search) in the functions.php and I deleted it, now the error is no more but the function was to search the posts based on tags and comments. Anyway, the function was unnecessary as the website has no tags and comments. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad it worked :)